# How to specify a request timeout for my HTTP server?

Tags: c, sockets, http, network-programming

I'm writing a HTTP server and I want to implement the 408 respond status code for it

this status code is for "REQUEST TIMEOUT" and I don't know how and when I should send this respond.

This is the definition for this status code from the RFC:
The server timed out waiting for the request. According to HTTP specifications: "The client did not produce a request within the time that the server was prepared to wait. The client MAY repeat the request without modifications at any later time."

The server is always looping and accepting connections I don't know how to calculate the request timing , and then send the respond if the time for sending request has reached some threshold.

Here is my code:

```
int sock, connected, bytes_recieved , _true = 1 , portNumber;
char send_data [1024] , recv_data[1024];      
struct sockaddr_in server_addr,client_addr;   
int sin_size;

 if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
{
    perror("Unable to create the Socket");
    exit(1);
}
  if (setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(const char*)&_true,sizeof(int)) == -1) {
    perror("Unable to Setsockopt");
    exit(1);
}
char *server_address="127.1.1.1";
portNumber=8080;
 server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
////htons function makes sure that numbers are stored in memory in network byte order (big indian)
server_addr.sin_port = htons(portNumber);
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.1.1.1");//inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1",&server_addr.sin_addr);//INADDR_ANY;

//save the host information for future purposes
string host=server_address+':'+to_string(portNumber);

//bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8); --This is for POSIX based systems

memset(&(server_addr.sin_zero),0,8);//sockaddr_in zero padding is needed
if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))==-1) //bind the socket to a local address
{
    perror("Unable to bind");
    exit(1);
}

if (listen(sock, 5) == -1) //listen to the socket with the specified waiting queue size
{
    perror(" Listen");
    exit(1);
}

cout << "MyHTTPServer waiting on port 8080" << endl;
fflush(stdout);

sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
connected = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&sin_size);

cout<< "I got a connection from (" << inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr) << "," << ntohs(client_addr.sin_port) << ')' << endl;
//fflush(stdout);
    char sendBuffer[500];
FILE *sendFile = fopen("foo.html", "r");
fseek(sendFile, 0L, SEEK_END);
int sz = ftell(sendFile);
fseek(sendFile, 0L, SEEK_SET);

char receiveBuffer[400];
recv(connected,receiveBuffer,sizeof(receiveBuffer),0);
cout << "Received:\n" << receiveBuffer << endl;

string s1;
s1="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-length: " + to_string(sz) + "\n";
std::vector<char> writable(s1.begin(), s1.end());
writable.push_back('\0');

//"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-length: 222\n"
strcpy(sendBuffer,(const char *)&writable[0]);
int c=send(connected,(const char*)&sendBuffer,strlen(&writable[0]),0);
printf("\nSent : %s\n",sendBuffer);
strcpy(sendBuffer,"Content-Type: text/html\n\n");
c=send(connected,(const char*)&sendBuffer,strlen("Content-Type: text/html\n\n"),0);
printf("\nSent : %s\n",sendBuffer);
    char send_buffer[500];


while( true )
{
    if(feof(sendFile))
    {
        break;
    }
    int numread = fread(send_buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), sz, sendFile);
    if( numread < 1 ) break; // EOF or error

    char *send_buffer_ptr = send_buffer;
    do
    {
        int numsent = send(connected,send_buffer_ptr, numread, 0);
        if( numsent < 1 ) // 0 if disconnected, otherwise error
        {
            if( numsent < 0 )
            {
                if( WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK )
                {
                    fd_set wfd;
                    FD_ZERO(&wfd);
                    FD_SET(connected, &wfd);

                    timeval tm;
                    tm.tv_sec = 10;
                    tm.tv_usec = 0;

                    if( select(0, NULL, &wfd, NULL, &tm) > 0 )
                        continue;
                }
            }

            break; // timeout or error
        }

        send_buffer_ptr += numsent;
        numread -= numsent;
        cout << "round";
    }
    while( numread > 0 );
}

//printf("\nSTATUS:%d",c);

WSACleanup();
```

Comment: @EJP's answer looks like it is enough for your purposes.  If you want an additional challenge you can think about dealing with things like slow client DOS attacks on your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set a read timeout with `setsockopt()` and `SO_RCVTIMEO`, and when you get a`read()` failure with

```
errno == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK
```

send the 408.

Comment: I'm writing the server side and I never use read , Do you mean the receive function?

After doing what you said does it mean that read function's "waiting time" for the data is set to what I have specified and when no data is sent in that duration the SO_RCVTIMEO error will be returned?

Comment: `read()` and `recv()` are equivalent for most purposes including this. I don't understand your second question but the read timeout starts when you enter the function.